# Is not there GUI for OpenDaylight anymore?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I am trying to program a virtual OpenFlow network by OpenDaylight and Mininet.
I tried it with the newest version of OpenDaylight 'Neon'. But I cannot install the feature 'dlux' and therefore I cannot use GUI. Cannot we use GUI anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Unfortunately, the DLUX project is no longer maintained and has been
removed from recent OpenDaylight releases.

Comment: Is there another framework in Java where I can use GUI?

Comment: I don't know of another GUI to use in ODL, but I remember hearing how another community (I think it was ONAP) had forked dlux and had it working on some version of ODL they were using. I don't know any more details than that. You can try an older version of ODL that still had dlux in it.